# Can stand-alone DNA (no nucleus, no membranes, organelles...etc.) create cells?

Tags: cell-biology, dna, abiogenesis

I have been searching for an answer to the following question as part of my research but can't find a direct/complete answer yet.

Can stand-alone DNA (no nucleus, no membranes, organelles...etc.) create cells?

From what I have learned about the biology of the cell, it seems to me that it is virtually impossible, but I will like an answer from an expert on the subject matter.

Regards,

Alfredo Archilla

Comment: Too much information is missing. E.g. what is the DNA standing alone in (water? Saline? Primordial soup? Eukaryotic cytoplasm minus organelles?) Can you define "cell"? If you're asking if DNA can do anything by itself, it can't. It's just a language, a code, a blueprint, a complex set of instructions. A blueprint can't build a building. DNA can't build a cell.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] (we know you have not) and then the Help on asking questions. You will see that you are expected to do some research and thinking of your own before posting a question and demonstrate it in the question. What have you learned about biology that makes you think it is impossible? If you are correct, this does not make a question of interest to biologists, but more the use of this site to check whether you have the correct answer to some assignment. If so, this is not what the site is for.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### DNA absolutely not, RNA maybe...

DNA can't even replicate itself without help

**RNA on the other hand makes almost everything**. It makes proteins, it makes DNA and we know it can at least bind and alter phospholipids. It can also make more of itself.

keep in mind the simplest living cells (prokaryotes) do not have nuclei nor most of the things we call organelles either.

[image]

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26876/

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC17937/

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7122455/

Comment: Ribosomes are necessary for protein synthesis. Without organelles, RNA is basically useless, depending on your definition of "cell". Without membranes, what does RNA's ability to alter membrane permeability matter? Without mitochondria, there's really no energy for the cell (again, depending on what you consider a "cell".) I think this answer is incorrect, but that's just an opinion. The OP has not given us enough useful information, but as stated, RNA can't make a cell.

Comment: RNA doesn't make proteins. Ribosomes (which include proteins) and tRNA-complexed amino acids make proteins. You need chaperones to help fold proteins, post-translational modifications need to be made for proteins to be active, and they need to be localized correctly. You also need a supply of lipids and phospholipids to build membranes. All of this requires pre-existing "stuff" that is not RNA. If your answer was correct, I could leave my total RNA extraction sitting around long enough and cells would form in it. Obviously, that doesn't happen.

Comment: @MattDMo all the functional parts and the bulk of the molecules of ribosomes are made of RNA, the proteins are only some stabilizers. tRNA is amazingly also made of RNA. you absolutely do NOT need chaperones to make proteins fold the right way. chaperones make it more efficient they are not necessary. one way you can tell is viruses often have no chaperones  or post translational modification for their proteins.  lastly make is not the same as made of, I never even tried to claim membranes were made of RNA.

Comment: @anongoodnurse most cells do not have mitochondria, mitochondria is only in eukaryotic cells. please learn what actually makes up the simplest cells. also ribosomes are made of RNA. Proteins synthesis in its simplest form is rRNA reading mRNA using tRNA carrying amino acids to make proteins.

Comment: Is a ribosome an organelle? Yes, it is (OP stated "no organelles".) Can a ribosome assemble itself from RNA? No, it cannot. Please don't tell me what to learn; I've had more schooling than most (Physician, former Molecular Biologist). Your answer is simply wrong. Surprising, given your profile claims, that you can't see the errors in your answer. Besides, you spent your answer on what the OP's didn't actually ask. Cells have cell membranes. @MattDMo is correct, as am I.

Comment: @anongoodnurse can a ribosome assemble itself, yes, https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ar2000474 I note no mention of mitochondria, do you still think they are necessary? If you define a cell as having a membrane sure it has a membrane could something without a membrane cells have membrane replicate, yes, could it make a membrane quite possibly.  you seem to be confused about what the OP asks, it is not is something without organelles IS a cell, it is could it make a cell.

Comment: I'm not going to argue anymore after this. Even "simple" [ribosomal formation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190308155533id_/http://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/eb02/06330e7fa3d3c75ab400f93024432da10410.pdf) requires the proper preexisting ribosomal proteins, a complete buttload of enzymes, rRNA, a cell-membrane dependent protein localization, etc. I'm not confused about what the OP asked. It's clear: "Can stand-alone DNA (no nucleus, no membranes, organelles...etc.) create cells?"